# High Scoring with Warmage in OMD2

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

For high scoring with warmage i use the vampire gaunlet-windbelt strat involving throwing mobs on to steam vents, which pushes them to a push-trap to a spring-trap (here orcs get flamed up with scorchers as well), and then the spring pops them into a grinder. I put a web-spinner in to the mix as well. It is easy to get 10x combo with this. However, I use up one slot for the mana-rage trinket because i just cannot manage the mana required for windbelt.

With sorceress however, it is easy to achieve 13x combo (remove manarage and add acid spray, assuming i get one smash combo as well with the wind belt). So i was looking for an answer for the mana management with warmage. Is it possible to get highscores with warmage given his mana pool?

Comment: I want to answer this, but don't have the references in front of me to source out a proper answer. I think there's a problem with your approach. The Warmage is not the Sorceress. You shouldn't be trying to force a mana heavy solution of a character with low mana. Other strategies better leverage his unique traps and abilities and it isn't too hard to achieve 13x with warmage in the right situation if you understand the combo mechanics in detail. Don't depend on mana so much and your mana problem clears right up. High Score can also be made up by higher averages so keep that in mind too.

Comment: @skovacs1 Can you share any warmage combo generation trap-set?